# Customizing the Subject Field in WordPress' Notification Emails?

Tags: customization, email, notifications

Can I customize and edit the subject field in the "Password Reset" notification mails sent from our multisite blogs? I have tried some plugins like My brand login and white label CMS  etc. But I can't edit this in password reset notifications .

Does anyone help me understand how to edit it ?

**Update:**

Today I tried with another installation .But it is not making any change.The Word 'wordpress' in from mail address is still there.I have added -

`add_filter ( 'wp_mail_from_name', 'my_filter_that_outputs_the_new_name' );`

to the code given by Doug .Am  I missing something?Could you help me to solve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can [**change them using a filter**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API#Filters). The filter hooks you want to use are:

1. For the **first email** message (confirming they really want to reset the password):

   - `'retrieve_password_title'`

     `'retrieve_password_message'`
2. For the **follow-up email** message (sending the new username and password):

   - `'password_reset_title'`

     `'password_reset_message'`

---

**Update:** To create and use these filters, put the following or similar code in your `functions.php` file:

```
function my_retrieve_password_subject_filter($old_subject) {
    // $old_subject is the default subject line created by WordPress.
    // (You don't have to use it.)

    $blogname = wp_specialchars_decode(get_option('blogname'), ENT_QUOTES);
    $subject = sprintf( __('[%s] Password Reset'), $blogname );
    // This is how WordPress creates the subject line. It looks like this:
    // [Doug's blog] Password Reset
    // You can change this to fit your own needs.

    // You have to return your new subject line:
    return $subject;
}

function my_retrieve_password_message_filter($old_message, $key) {
    // $old_message is the default message already created by WordPress.
    // (You don't have to use it.)
    // $key is the password-like token that allows the user to get 
    // a new password

    $message = __('Someone has asked to reset the password for the following site and username.') . "\r\n\r\n";
    $message .= network_site_url() . "\r\n\r\n";
    $message .= sprintf(__('Username: %s'), $user_login) . "\r\n\r\n";
    $message .= __('To reset your password visit the following address, otherwise just ignore this email and nothing will happen.') . "\r\n\r\n";
    $message .= network_site_url("wp-login.php?action=rp&key=$key&login=" . rawurlencode($user_login), 'login') . "\r\n";

    // This is how WordPress creates the message. 
    // You can change this to meet your own needs.

    // You have to return your new message:
    return $message;
}

// To get these filters up and running:
add_filter ( 'retrieve_password_title', 'my_retrieve_password_subject_filter', 10, 1 );
add_filter ( 'retrieve_password_message', 'my_retrieve_password_message_filter', 10, 2 );
```

You would do something similar if you also want to modify the **follow-up email**. Use the [WordPress code](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.0.1/wp-login.php#L213) as a guide for creating the subject line and message (look for the variables `$title` and `$message`).

Comment: I've added some sample code for creating the filters above. See the Codex article I linked to for more detail.

Comment: Thanks for your kind help . I will try it.
Could you also help me customizing the From address in Password Reset notification mails-"WordPress <admin@mydomain.com> .Here WordPress should be replaced with my site name .

Comment: add_filter ( 'wp_mail_from_name', 'my_filter_that_outputs_the_new_name' );

Comment: Success !
Wordpress has been replaced with the mail address -Admin .

Thank you for helping me !

Comment: You're quite welcome! Glad I could help.

Comment: Today I tried with another installation .But it is not making any change.The Word 'wordpress' in from mail address is not changing . I think I am missing something.I have added -add_filter ( 'wp_mail_from_name', 'my_filter_that_outputs_the_new_name' );  
to the above code you given .Could you help me to solve this?

Comment: is it possible to include the ip address of the requester of the change?